# Exception: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: java

I have the below piece of code:

```
Integer mRuntime = (Integer) movie.get("runtime");
String movieRuntime;
if(mRuntime == null){
    movieRuntime="*Not Available*";
} else{
    movieRuntime = String.valueOf(mRuntime);
}
```

In the above code I am trying to check the value of runtime which is an integer and trying to convert the value to String if it is not NULL. if it is null I am writing a custom message to String telling that it is not available.

But when I try to execute the code I am getting the below message:

```
nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

at

```
Integer mRuntime = (Integer) movie.get("runtime");
```

Comment: "I am trying to check the value of runtime which is an integer" based on your error message `(Integer) movie.get("runtime")` seems to return string, not integer. Double check it.

Comment: In my case, this error was reported in fault... I was using `Integer.toString(IntegerObject)` and it gave me this error, but it's happy with `IntegerObject.toString()`... And yes, that really is an Integer, and I really did get this error...

Comment: Scratch that, only `String.valueOf()` actually works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value stored under the key `runtime` is not of type `Integer` you will invariably run into this `ClassCastException`. You can rewrite the thing as follows, assuming movies is a `Map`:

```
String movieRuntime;
if (!movies.containsKey("runtime")) {
    movieRuntime="*Not Available*";
} else if (movies.get("runtime") instanceof Integer){
    movieRuntime = String.valueOf(movies.get("runtime"));
}
// add an else case for all the other types
```

Answer (score 0):

`movie.get("runtime")` returns a `String`. You want a `String`. You're good. Just do this:

```
String movieRuntime = movies.get("runtime");
if (movieRuntime == null) {
    movieRuntime = "*Not Available*";
}
```